# Is there a way to use characters instead of numbers for axes tick marks in R (ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following code the produces a graph.

```
Bloom <- read.table("Phenology Example.txt", header = T)

library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

x  <- Bloom$Julian_Date
A <- Bloom$Bloom_A
B <- Bloom$Bloom_B
df <- data.frame(x, A, B)

df2 <- melt(data = df, id.vars = "x")

ggplot(data = df2, aes(x = x, y = value, color = variable)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = round(seq(min(0), max(1), by = 1),1)) +
  labs(title = "Example", 
       x = "Date",
       y = "Status", 
       colour = "Legend") +
  xlim(120,131)
```

Result of returning Bloom:

```
    ID    Julian_Date   A       B
1   1         120       0       0
2   2         121       0       0
3   3         122       1       0
4   4         123       1       0
5   5         124       1       0
6   6         125       1       1
7   7         126       1       1
8   8         127       1       1
9   9         128       0       1
10 10         129       0       1
11 11         130       0       1
12 12         131       0       0
```

Basically, my graph shows two values along the y-axis: a 0 (indicating that a condition is not being met at a given date) and a 1 (indicating that a condition is being met at a given date). Is there any way to change the 0 and 1 on the y-axis to a word or set of words, such as "Met" or "Not Met"?

It isn't a huge deal, but I feel like it would be more visually appealing and would make more sense.
[image: Resulting graph of running the above code]

Answer (score 2):

You can convert `df2$value` into a factor, where the values are Met/Not Met then you remove `+ scale_y_continuous(...)` because ggplot will handle it properly automatically.

OR

You can use `+ scale_y_discrete(labels = c("Not Met","Met"))`. But to use this, you need to change your data from 0,1 to 1,2, otherwise you get a strange display:

```
df2$value <- df2$value + 1 # change data

ggplot(data = df2, aes(x = x, y = value, color = variable)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_y_discrete(labels = c("Met","Not Met")) +
  labs(title = "Example", 
       x = "Date",
       y = "Status", 
       colour = "Legend") +
  xlim(120,131)
```

[image: plot with discrete scale]

Comment: I was attempting to describe the issues that I was having with display, but I lost connection. Thank you for that clarification, I could not figure out how to change the oddness of that.

Comment: It's ok. Just hard to diagnose a problem you can't reproduce. Incentives work well for reproducible examples :)